# Qt error: c: command not found / qmake could not locate g++ compiler

Tags: linux, qt, qt5, qt-creator, bitbake

I have 2 versions of SDK for Qt Creator: Compiled from Open Source and Compiled from bitbake.

The Open Source SDK is working fine,  but the bitbake one is having trouble recognizing the compiler.  I have added the g++ compiler to `build & Run` and `source environment-setup-cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi`as well.

> make: c: Command not found make: [moc_utils.o] Error 127 (ignored)
>
> make:
>   Wl,-rpath-link,/opt/poky/charles/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib:
>
> Command not found make: [quicknanobrowser] Error 127 (ignored)

Here is the error one Compiler Log:

> 14:27:55: Running steps for project quicknanobrowser...
>
> 14:27:55:
>   Starting:
>   "/opt/poky/charles/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/qt5/qmake"
>   /home/hbulab/Qt5.5.1/Examples/Qt-5.5/webengine/quicknanobrowser/quicknanobrowser.pro
>   -r -spec linux-oe-g++ CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=declarative_debug CONFIG+=qml_debug
>
> 14:27:55: The process
>   "/opt/poky/charles/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/qt5/qmake"
>   exited normally.
>
> 14:27:55: Starting: "/usr/bin/make"
>
> c -pipe  -g
>   -DLINUX=1 -DEGL_API_FB=1 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_WEBENGINE_LIB -DQT_QUICK_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_QML_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I.

and here is the one without error,  we could see that the `make` could not find the g++ compiler.  How do I fix it?

> 14:29:08: Running steps for project quicknanobrowser... 14:29:08:
>   Starting: "/opt/hio-imx6dl-board/opt/Qt5daisy/bin/qmake"
>   /home/hbulab/Qt5.5.1/Examples/Qt-5.5/webengine/quicknanobrowser/quicknanobrowser.pro
>   -r -spec devices/linux-imx6-g++ CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=declarative_debug CONFIG+=qml_debug
>
> 14:29:09: The process
>   "/opt/hio-imx6dl-board/opt/Qt5daisy/bin/qmake" exited normally.
>
> 14:29:09: Starting: "/usr/bin/make"
>
> /opt/poky/1.6.1/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++
>   -c -pipe -march=armv7-a -mfpu=neon -DLINUX=1 -DEGL_API_FB=1 -mfloat-abi=hard -g -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_WEBENGINE_LIB -DQT_QUICK_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_QML_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I.

MakeFile Information:

```
MAKEFILE      = Makefile

####### Compiler, tools and options

CC            = $(OE_QMAKE_CC)
CXX           = $(OE_QMAKE_CXX)
DEFINES       = -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_WEBENGINE_LIB -DQT_QUICK_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_QML_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB
CFLAGS        = -pipe $(OE_QMAKE_CFLAGS) -g -DLINUX=1 -DEGL_API_FB=1 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC $(DEFINES)
CXXFLAGS      = -pipe $(OE_QMAKE_CXXFLAGS) -g -DLINUX=1 -DEGL_API_FB=1 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC $(DEFINES)
INCPATH       = -I../../../Qt5.5.1/Examples/Qt-5.5/webengine/quicknanobrowser -I. -isystem /opt/poky/charles/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/qt5 -isystem /opt/poky/charles/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/qt5/QtWebEngine -isystem /opt/poky/charles/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/qt5/QtQuick -isystem /opt/poky/charles/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets -isystem /opt/poky/charles/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/qt5/QtGui -isystem /opt/poky/charles/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/qt5/QtQml -isystem /opt/poky/charles/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/qt5/QtNetwork -isystem /opt/poky/charles/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -I/opt/poky/charles/sysroots/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/qt5/mkspecs/linux-oe-g++
QMAKE         = /opt/poky/charles/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/qt5/qmake
```

Comment: Have you re-run `qmake` when changing SDK's? How does the start of the generated Makefile look like? Does it include  a line like `CXX = $(OE_QMAKE_CXX)`? If so, what does running `echo $OE_QMAKE_CXX` immediately after getting the error give you?

Comment: How do I re-run qmake? All I did was to switch the Kits from Qt Creator. Since it fail at make, it didn't create any MakeFile

Comment: Ok, looking at the traces, it looks like qmake is being run. Do you have everything in  `source environment-setup-cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi` configured in QtCreator? (Or sourced in the same shell that starts QtCreator?). As the build fails during compilation, `${CC}` is being empty, qmake will have created a Makefile for you. This is also indicated in your logs, as qmake exited normally. What happens if you try to run qmake and make in a shell?

Comment: I did not add anything other than the g++ compiler, the qmake, and add a kits with the sysroot.  `echo $OE_QMAKE_CXX` return empty.  I could ran qmake and make in shell, It create the makefile as the same as above, but make return the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `${OE_QMAKE_CXX}` is empty, that indicates to me that you haven't source `environment-setup-cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabiasenvironment-setup-cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi`.

This should work to compile by hand:

```
 . /opt/poky/charles/environment-setup-cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi
 echo $OE_QMAKE_CXX
 qmake
 make
```

(Assuming you don't need to pass any extra arguments to qmake).

Then do the following:

```
 . /opt/poky/charles/environment-setup-cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi
 echo $OE_QMAKE_CXX
 qtcreator
```

Note that you should start qtcreator from the same shell that you source `environment-setup-cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi` in.

This should get you going. Otherwise I'd suggest starting by getting a small, simple Qt appliction building correctly.

For more in configuring QtCreator, you could for instance have a look at [how to setup QtCreator for cross-compilation](http://developer.toradex.com/knowledge-base/how-to-set-up-qt-creator-to-cross-compile-for-embedded-linux#Configure_Qt_Creator).

## Update

As it seems that Qt5 isn't included in the SDK at all, we first have to generate a suitable SDK. My preferred way:

```
 bitbake your-image -c populate_sdk
```

This works, as long as your image recipe includes

```
 inherit populate_sdk_qt5
```

That would give you an SDK, whose sysroot would match your image.

The "older" way, is to use a special toolchain recipe. For Qt5 that would be `meta-toolchain-qt5`, or some recipe that includes/requires that one. In this case, you would run:

```
  bitbake meta-toolchain-qt5
```

Though, the recommended way is to use the image specific SDK.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  The $OE_QMAKE_CXX is still empty after I have sourced environment.  So I took a step back and compare the environment files.  Turn out all the `export OE_QMAKE` are missing.  Do you know why is it that way?

Comment: Oh, that's a completely different thing. In that case, I assume that your SDK lacks Qt. Se my addition above.

Comment: The one I did was actually from `meta-toolchain-qt5`.  It worked for the 5.2.1 version.  Ever since I switch to 5.5.1 and added Qt webengine.  Everything goes wrong.

Comment: Please, double check the SDK once again. I've just compiled a new SDK, based on the upcoming 2.1 release; and this one, as well as SDK's based on 1.6, 1.8, and 2.0 all set `OE_QMAKE_CXX`. However, in newer versions, the `OE_QMAKE*`exports aren't done in `environment-setup-cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi`, but rather in a file sourced by that script. The file in question is `$OECORE_NATIVE_SYSROOT/environment-setup.d/qt5.sh`. Check if this one exists. Otherwise, the standard info request regarding OE-version etc applies.

Comment: I have compiled another SDK from bitbake and the `environment setup` file is the same, missing all the `OE_QMAKE`, do you know which file I should look into?

Comment: is it normal to have the path like this with double slash`//`?  from bitbake-e meta-toolchain-qt5
`toolchain_create_sdk_siteconfig /mountdata/hio-yocto-bsp/qt5jethro/qt5/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/meta-toolchain-qt5/1.0-r0/sdk/image//opt/poky/1.6.1/site-config-cortexa9hf-vfp$` ..........................


`toolchain_create_sdk_env_script /mountdata/hio-yocto-bsp/qt5jethro/qt5/tmp/work/cortexa9hf-vfp-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/meta-toolchain-qt5/1.0-r0/sdk/image//opt/poky/1.6.1/environment-setup-cortexa9$`

Comment: The double slashes shouldn't be any problem. Look in the native sysroot of the SDK. There should be a `qt5.sh` inside the `environment-setup.d` there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107979/discussion-between-lightens-and-anders).